# How to count the number of entries in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the number of times the account number occurs per each loan ID, instead of per each lt.type.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.ACCOUNTNUMBER AS [Account Number]
    , CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST) AS [Member Name]
    , l.id AS [Loan ID]
    , COUNT(a.ACCOUNTNUMBER)
        OVER(partition by a.ACCOUNTNUMBER) as [Number of Tracking Record] 
    , n.EMAIL AS [Email]
    , n.HOMEPHONE AS [Phone Number]
FROM dbo.account a
INNER JOIN dbo.LOAN l
    ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = l.PARENTACCOUNT
INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
    ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
    AND l.ID = lt.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.NAME n 
    ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = n.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE lt.type = 46
    AND l.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND lt.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
    AND n.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND l.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
    AND lt.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
    AND n.type = 0
GROUP BY a.ACCOUNTNUMBER, n.FIRST, n.MIDDLE, n.LAST, l.id, n.email, 
n.HOMEPHONE, lt.type
) MyQuery
WHERE MyQuery.[Number of Tracking Record] >= 2
GROUP BY [Account Number], [Member Name], [Loan ID], [Number of Tracking 
Record], [Email], [Phone Number]
ORDER BY [Account Number]
```

[Here's what my query is giving me now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUpKN.png)

[Here's what the result should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUced.png)

Comment: I think you'll want to look into windowing functions

Comment: Hint: `COUNT() OVER()` Or maybe you want `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: That helps, but I still need to filter it so that I only have the entries with 3 or more.

Comment: What is the subquery? I don't see a subquery. I see tables joined. What do you consider the main table and what do you consider the sub-table?

Comment: @ErikE, I have changed the query since I posted. I apologize.
My main question is now that I have the number of times the account number is listed, how do I filter it so that I only have the account numbers listed 3 times or more.

Comment: You want individual lines for each one, but only when there are 3o or more?

Comment: @ErikE, yes. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ACCOUNTNUMBER AS [Account Number]
    , CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST) AS [Member Name]
    , l.id AS [Loan ID]
    , n.EMAIL AS [Email]
    , n.HOMEPHONE AS [Phone Number],
    , COUNT(*) AS [Number of Tracking Record 46]
FROM dbo.account a
INNER JOIN dbo.LOAN l
ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = l.PARENTACCOUNT
INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
AND l.ID = lt.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.NAME n 
ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = n.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE lt.type = 46
AND l.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()),
112)
AND lt.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()),
112)
AND a.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
AND lt.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
GROUP BY  a.ACCOUNTNUMBER, CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST), l.id , n.EMAIL, n.HOMEPHONE 
HAVING count (*) >= 3
ORDER BY a.ACCOUNTNUMBER
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's still giving me the total number of account number entries.

Comment: @lexirainbow Sample data and result will help to answer your question at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be very rude by reformatting your query, just so I can see it better. My apologies.

```
DECLARE @ProcessDate varchar(8) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day, -1, GetDate()), 112);
WITH Accounts AS (
   SELECT
      [Account Number] = a.ACCOUNTNUMBER,
      [Member Name] = CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST),
      [Loan ID] = l.id,
      [Number of Tracking Record] = Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ACCOUNTNUMBER),
      Email = n.EMAIL AS [Email],
      [Phone Number] = n.HOMEPHONE
   FROM
      dbo.account a
      INNER JOIN dbo.LOAN l
         ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = l.PARENTACCOUNT
      INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
         ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
         AND l.ID = lt.ID
      INNER JOIN dbo.NAME n 
         ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = n.PARENTACCOUNT
      WHERE
         lt.type = 46
         AND l.ProcessDate = @ProcessDate
         AND lt.ProcessDate = @ProcessDate
         AND a.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
         AND lt.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM
  Accounts a
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT A3.[Account Number]
     FROM Accounts a3
     GROUP BY a3.[Account Number]
     HAVING Count(*) >= 3
  ) a3
     ON a.[Account Number] = a3.[Account Number]
ORDER BY
   a.ACCOUNTNUMBER;
```

Note that you this may result in the server running the basic query in the CTE twice. If that is a problem, then instead, insert the results into a temp table and perform the final query against that.

P.S. It's awful if `ProcessDate` really is a text column...

P.P.S Here is an alternate outer query. Test to see which performs better:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Accounts a
WHERE
  EXISTS(
     SELECT *
     FROM Accounts a3
     WHERE
       a.[Account Number] = a3.[Account Number]
       AND [Number of Tracking Record] = 3
  ) 
ORDER BY
   a.ACCOUNTNUMBER;
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but both are giving me the total number of accounts in the "Number of Tracking Record" field

Comment: And what is supposed to be there instead? I can write ANY QUERY you can imagine, so if I can't write your query it's because there isn't enough information. Please... explain it better!

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a lot of things unnecessarily and I don't think you really understand the purpose grouping. I believe you probably just need to strip all that stuff out.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT a.ACCOUNTNUMBER AS [Account Number]
    , CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST) AS [Member Name]
    , l.id AS [Loan ID]
    , COUNT(a.ACCOUNTNUMBER) OVER (partition by l.id) as [Number of Tracking Record] 
    , n.EMAIL AS [Email]
    , n.HOMEPHONE AS [Phone Number]
FROM dbo.account a
INNER JOIN dbo.LOAN l
    ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = l.PARENTACCOUNT
INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
    ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
    AND l.ID = lt.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.NAME n 
    ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = n.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE lt.type = 46
    AND l.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND lt.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
    AND n.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND a.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND l.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
    AND lt.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
    AND n.type = 0
) MyQuery
WHERE MyQuery.[Number of Tracking Record] >= 2
ORDER BY [Account Number];
```